# How to make the caption font size bigger with "\adjustbox"?

Tags: tables, captions, fontsize

I want to make the font size of a table's caption bigger. I usually do it with no issues. However, this time I can't make it work with "\adjustbox". This is what I have:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
      
\usepackage{latexsym}% Package loading the LaTeX symbol.
\usepackage{graphicx}% Package necessary to put graphics in your TeX document
\usepackage{setspace}% Package for changing space between the lines
\usepackage{fancyhdr}% Package for making the fancy headers with names of authors and title of paper 
\usepackage{lscape}  % Package allowing to put your text in landscape
\usepackage{amsmath} % An extension package for LaTeX that provides various features to facilitate writing math formulas and to improve the typographical quality of their output
\usepackage{mathrsfs}    
\usepackage{longtable,epsfig}  
\usepackage{longtable,pdflscape}   
\usepackage[center,tight,small]{subfigure} 
\usepackage[font=large,skip=2pt,labelfont=bf,singlelinecheck=false,justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{natbib}         
\usepackage{epigraph}        
\usepackage{threeparttable}           
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}  
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{epstopdf}      
\usepackage{multirow}    
\usepackage{titlesec}  
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[hang]{footmisc}
\setlength{\footnotemargin}{2mm}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{graphicx}     
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}    

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{adjustbox}{width=1\textwidth}
\begin{threeparttable}
\captionsetup{font= large}
\caption{Identifying Sign Restrictions}
\label{tab: tab3}
\vspace{0.2cm}
\setlength\extrarowheight{-10pt}
\begin{tabular}{lccccccc} 
    \toprule

     & Gov. Rev & Gov. Exp & EONIA & DFPA & GDP & HICP & CISS\\
    \midrule

     \textit{Fiscal Policy Shock} & $+$ &  & & & $-$ & $-$ &\\
    
     \textit{Monetary Policy Shock}  &  & & $+$ & & $-$ & $-$ &\\
   
     \textit{DFPA Shock}      & $+$ & $-$ & & $-$ & &  &\\

\bottomrule

\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}
\linespread{1}\small
\item \textit{Note}: This table shows the sign restrictions on the impulse responses for each identified shock. A \enquote{$+$} means that the impulse response of the variable in question is restricted to be positive for twelve months following the shock, including the month of impact. Likewise, a \enquote{$-$} indicates a negative response. A blank entry indicates that no restrictions have been imposed.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't use `adjustbox` on a table, as this will, as you observed, lead to inconsistent font sizes thoughout the document. There are better methods to make sure a table fits into the available space.

Comment: What's the purpose of the empty first column in your table? Couldn't you just remove that column in order to save some space?

Comment: Please clean up your preamble and make sure you don't load packages more than once, especially not with confilcting options. (The caption package is loaded twice with differing `font` options...)

Comment: @leandriis thank you for your comments. The purpose is to leave it empty because there is no row name matching the first col

Comment: If the column is entirely empty, why can't you just remove it?

Comment: just edited, got confused, you were right

Comment: Unrelated don't load epsfig package into any document written this century

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two different versions of your table that fit into the available textwidth without using `adjustbox`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{threeparttable}            
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage[font=large,skip=2pt,labelfont=bf,singlelinecheck=false,justification=centering]{caption}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\begin{document}


\begin{table}
\small
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Identifying Sign Restrictions}
\label{tab: tab3}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}>{\itshape}lccccccc} 
    \toprule
      & \thead{Gov.\\ Rev} & \thead{Gov.\\ Exp} & \thead{EONIA} & \thead{DFPA} & \thead{GDP} & \thead{HICP} & \thead{CISS}\\
    \midrule
     Fiscal Policy Shock & $+$ &  & & & $-$ & $-$ &\\
     Monetary Policy Shock  &  & & $+$ & & $-$ & $-$ &\\
    DFPA Shock      & $+$ & $-$ & & $-$ & &  &\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]
 \setlength\labelsep{0pt} 
\linespread{1}\small
\item \textit{Note}: This table shows the sign restrictions on the impulse responses for each identified shock. A \enquote{$+$} means that the impulse response of the variable in question is restricted to be positive for twelve months following the shock, including the month of impact. Likewise, a \enquote{$-$} indicates a negative response. A blank entry indicates that no restrictions have been imposed.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\small
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Identifying Sign Restrictions}
\label{tab: tab3}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}>{\itshape\raggedright\arraybackslash}Xccccccc@{}} 
    \toprule
      & Gov. Rev & Gov. Exp & EONIA & DFPA & GDP & HICP & CISS\\
    \midrule
     Fiscal Policy Shock & $+$ &  & & & $-$ & $-$ &\\ \addlinespace
     Monetary Policy Shock  &  & & $+$ & & $-$ & $-$ &\\ \addlinespace
    DFPA Shock      & $+$ & $-$ & & $-$ & &  &\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]
 \setlength\labelsep{0pt} 
\linespread{1}\small
\item \textit{Note}: This table shows the sign restrictions on the impulse responses for each identified shock. A \enquote{$+$} means that the impulse response of the variable in question is restricted to be positive for twelve months following the shock, including the month of impact. Likewise, a \enquote{$-$} indicates a negative response. A blank entry indicates that no restrictions have been imposed.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks a lot! Super helpful!